# How to remove chromium browser which was installed via deb file offline?

Tags: chromium, browser

I had installed `chromium-browser` offline from `.deb` file. Now I want to remove it but I am not able to do it.

`apt` just returns:

```
Package 'chromium-browser' is not installed, so not removed.
```

How to remove it ?

Comment: Run `sudo updatedb` and then run `locate chromium-browser`. What do you see?

Comment: Are you sure that 'chromium-browser' is the exact name of the package you installed? Are you sure it was a deb instead of a Snap or and AppImage or a Flatpack or something else?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to remove it by using a Package Manager like "Ubuntu Software Center" or "Synaptic Package Manager", see the following images for guidance:

Ubuntu Software Center:
[image: ubuntu software center removing chromium browser]

Synaptic Package Manager:
[image: synaptic package manager removing chromium browser]

If you need a step by step solution, you could check [this link](http://write.flossmanuals.net/chromium/removing-chromium-from-ubuntu/).

Hope it helps.